# datatable's <div class="dataTables_scroll"> not making calculations

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable

As you can see on this image:

[click to see the image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1iu5c8i3qjch0vr/Untitled-1%20copy.jpg)

the scrollbar is not in the right place unlike what datatable must have see "datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/"

This is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xawixawxaw/9PCW5/2/), hope this helps.

As I inspect on datatable's website, it seems like the `<div class="dataTables_scroll">` is not making any plugin-generated-css. I think it's the reason why the position of the wrappers is not in the right place.
But what should I do?

Thanks for the help

Comment: with out your code I cannot help you. Can you make jsfiddle

Comment: hey @Selva, tnx for the interest! here i try to make one http://jsfiddle.net/xawixawxaw/9PCW5/2/ hope this helps.